# Clarification on Einstein Summation Convention

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing a MOOC quiz question on sun's rays hitting an object and casting a shadow on the ground in a 3D space. The variables are listed below and visualized in an illustration beneath that:

1. Space: 3D, with unit vectors $\hat{e}_1$ to $\hat{e}_3$
2. Vector $\hat{s}$: Unit vector of sun's rays (should be a column vector with 3 elements)
3. Vector $r$: Any point on an object in the space.
4. Vector $r'$: $r$ projected onto the ground due to shadow cast when sun's rays hits object.

[image: Visual Depiction of Problem]

The question asked for this (equation (1)) to be represented in Einstein's Summation notation:

$$r' = r - \frac{\hat{s}\left(r \cdot \hat{e}_3\right)}{\hat{s}\cdot \hat{e}_3} \tag 1$$

These are 3 options (equations (2),(3, and (4)) which were listed to be correct (indices are the $i$'s and $j$'s outside the brackets):

\begin{align} r'_i &= r_i - \frac{s_i (\hat{e}_3)_j r_j}{(\hat{s}\cdot \hat{e}_3)} \tag 2 \\
 r'_i &= \left(I_{ij} - \frac{s_i[\hat{e}_3]_j }{ \hat{s}\cdot \hat{e}_3}\right)r_j \tag 3 \\
 r'_i &= \left(I_{ij} - \frac{s_i(I)_{i=3,j} }{ \hat{s}\cdot \hat{e}_3}\right)r_j \tag 4
\end{align}
Where $I$ is an identity matrix.

Questions:
(1) Can someone help to explain how they are equivalent representations?
(2) What is $[\hat{e}_3]_j$? Isn't it a $3\times 1$ column matrix - doesn't that mean $j=1$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Made some minor edits for equations 3 and 4. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A bit of a preamble

- If $\{e_i\}_i$ forms a base, then you can write any vector ${\bf x}$ as

$$
x = x_i \hat{\bf e}_i \tag{a}
$$

- If the base is orthonormal you have

$$
\hat{\bf e}_i \cdot \hat{\bf e}_j = \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 & i =j \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases} \equiv I_{ij} \tag{b}
$$

- If the base is orthonormal and ${\bf x}, {\bf y}$ are vectors

$$
{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y} \stackrel{(a)}{=} (x_i \hat{\bf e}_i)\cdot (y_j \hat{\bf e}_j) \stackrel{(b)}{=} x_i y_j \delta_{ij} = x_i y_i \tag{c}
$$

- In an orthonormal basis you can calculate the component of vector ${\bf x}$ along the direction $j$ fairly easy

$$
{\bf x}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_j = (x_i \hat{\bf e}_i) \cdot \hat{\bf e}_j = x_i \delta_{ij} = x_j \tag{d}
$$

- As a corollary the $j$-th component of the vector $\hat{\bf e}_i$ is simply 
  $$
  \hat{\bf e}_i \cdot \hat{\bf e}_j = \delta_{ij} \tag{e}
  $$

> Now your problem

\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf r}' &=& {\bf r} - \hat{\bf s} \frac{{\bf r}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3}{\hat{\bf s}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3} \\
r'_i &=& r_i - s_i \frac{{\bf r}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3}{\hat{\bf s}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3} \\
&\stackrel{(c)}{=}& r_i - s_i \frac{r_j [e_3]_j}{\hat{\bf s}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3} \\
&=& r_i -  \frac{s_i [e_3]_j}{\hat{\bf s}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3}r_j \tag{2} \\
&\stackrel{(e)}{=}& r_j \delta_{ij} - \frac{s_i \delta_{3j}}{\hat{\bf s}\cdot \hat{\bf e}_3}r_j \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

As for your last question $[e_3]_j$ means the $j$-th component of the vector $\hat{\bf e}_3$ in the base $\{\hat{\bf e}_i \}_i$ which is just $\delta_{3j}$ (see Eq (e) above)

Comment: Hi! Could you help to explain this notation $\{e_i\}_i$?

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, of course, it is just a short for the set $\{ e_1, e_2, \cdots\}$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks :)